# iReport 6.0.1 to 4.1.1

Tags: jasper-reports

I have a report made with ireport 6.0.1, I have to modify the not compatible content to open it with 4.1.1 version.
I deleted the **uuid**, **borderSplitType="DrawBorders"** on the frames, now I have the **evaluationTime="Master"** property, should it be changed to **evaluationTime="Report"**?

PS : I didn't find any documentation on the differences between the two versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configuring Jaspersoft Studio to Source .jrxml version 4.1.1 should automatically modify the source as needed to be compatible with 4.1.1.

https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide/v630/setting-compatibility-earlier-versions

Further:

EvaluationTimeEnum in 4.1.1:
https://javadoc.io/static/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/4.1.1/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html

EvaluationTimeEnum in 6.0.0:
https://javadoc.io/static/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports/6.0.0/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/type/EvaluationTimeEnum.html

Please also have a read of Chapter "7.3.1 Evaluation Time" in the current 'TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio User Guide' https://community.jaspersoft.com/documentation/v8-v80-v800/tibco-jaspersoft-studio-user-guide to get a better understanding of Evaluation Time.